# BuyFlow UI needs to be shown : Google Pay Integration Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, google-pay

While integrating Google Pay I'm getting ResolvableApiException after on click of Buy With GPay button and its showing dialog with following error.
"An unexpected error has occured. Please try again later. [OR_BIEBD_01]"

I've followed all the steps given in the sample and generate Payment JSON data.

Payment JSON Data ::

```
 {
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "apiVersionMinor": 0,
  "allowedPaymentMethods": [
    {
      "type": "CARD",
      "parameters": {
        "allowedAuthMethods": [
          "PAN_ONLY",
          "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"
        ],
        "allowedCardNetworks": [
          "AMEX",
          "DISCOVER",
          "INTERAC",
          "JCB",
          "MASTERCARD",
          "VISA"
        ],
        "billingAddressRequired": false
      },
      "tokenizationSpecification": {
        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
        "parameters": {
          "gateway": "example",
          "gatewayMerchantId": "gatewayMerchantId"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "transactionInfo": {
    "totalPrice": "10.0",
    "totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
    "countryCode": "KSA",
    "currencyCode": "SAR",
    "checkoutOption": "COMPLETE_IMMEDIATE_PURCHASE"
  },
  "merchantInfo": {
    "merchantName": "Example Merchant",
    "merchantId": "01234567890123456789"
  },
  "shippingAddressRequired": false,
  "shippingAddressParameters": {
    "phoneNumberRequired": false,
    "allowedCountryCodes": [
      "KSA"
    ]
  }
}
```

"

ResolvableApiException :

```
{
  "zza": {},
  "zzb": {
    "zza": {},
    "zzb": [],
    "zzc": false
  },
  "zzc": true,
  "zzd": false,
  "zzf": {
    "mStatus": {
      "zzb": 1,
      "zzc": 6,
      "zzd": "BuyFlow UI needs to be shown.",
      "zze": {}
    },
    "detailMessage": "6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown.",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "suppressedExceptions": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use `ISO 3166-1 alpha-2` country code values for `countryCode` and `allowedCountryCodes`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2